# Ambiguous reference to member 'init(from:)' for Enum

Tags: swift, enums

Let's say we have this Enum:

```
enum NumberEnumSpecial: Int32 {
    case two = 2, three = 3
}
```

I would like to init it with a Int32, so I use this:

```
    let myEnum = NumberEnumSpecial.init(rawValue: 2)
```

This works in a playground project but not in my regular App project. I'm getting this error for the exact same code:

```
Ambiguous reference to member 'init(from:)'
```

[image]

```
/Users/sjoerd/GitHub/flitsmeister-ios/app/Flitsmeister7/Model/Melding/DangerZone.swift:91:22: error: ambiguous reference to member 'init(from:)'
        let myEnum = NumberEnumSpecial.init(rawValue: 2)
                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Swift.RawRepresentable:2:24: note: found this candidate
    public convenience init(from decoder: Decoder) throws
                       ^
Swift.RawRepresentable:2:24: note: found this candidate
    public convenience init(from decoder: Decoder) throws
                       ^
Swift.RawRepresentable:2:24: note: found this candidate
    public convenience init(from decoder: Decoder) throws
                       ^
Swift.RawRepresentable:2:24: note: found this candidate
    public convenience init(from decoder: Decoder) throws
                       ^
Swift.RawRepresentable:2:24: note: found this candidate
    public convenience init(from decoder: Decoder) throws
                       ^
Swift.RawRepresentable:2:24: note: found this candidate
    public convenience init(from decoder: Decoder) throws
                       ^
Swift.RawRepresentable:2:24: note: found this candidate
    public convenience init(from decoder: Decoder) throws
                       ^
Swift.RawRepresentable:2:24: note: found this candidate
    public convenience init(from decoder: Decoder) throws
                       ^
Swift.RawRepresentable:2:24: note: found this candidate
    public convenience init(from decoder: Decoder) throws
                       ^
Swift.RawRepresentable:2:24: note: found this candidate
    public convenience init(from decoder: Decoder) throws
                       ^
Swift.RawRepresentable:2:24: note: found this candidate
    public convenience init(from decoder: Decoder) throws
                       ^
Swift.RawRepresentable:2:24: note: found this candidate
    public convenience init(from decoder: Decoder) throws
                       ^
Swift.RawRepresentable:2:24: note: found this candidate
    public convenience init(from decoder: Decoder) throws
                       ^
Swift.RawRepresentable:2:24: note: found this candidate
    public convenience init(from decoder: Decoder) throws
                       ^



Build failed    13/10/2017, 09:32
```

Clicking on the candidates has no effect.

If you ask me there seems to be a Enum somewhere in the code with an implementation for init(from) causing this error on my Enum. But searching for this text gives me no results.

What is this error and how can find out what is causing this ?

Using Swift 3.2 and XCode9.0

Currently workaround:

```
enum NumberEnumSpecial: Int32 {
    case two = 2, three = 3

    init?(withSpecialNumber number : Int32) {
          self.init(rawValue: number)
    }
}
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Can you show the full compiler error message from the Report navigator?

Comment: There should be a button at the right end of the "Compile DangerZone.swift" line which shows the compiler messages as *text.* – Show that text, not a screenshot.

Comment: Full log: https://pastebin.com/18VigRqw

Comment: I am confused now. You tagged the question with [swift3], but `protocol Decoder` was introduced in Swift 4, as far as I know.

Comment: Is the file with `NumberEnumSpecial` included in the project target?

Comment: Weird! Project settings says Swift language version: Swift 3.2 It's Xcode 9.0

Comment: @Sulthan I see it in the project navigator and target membership is activated. This code works: let myEnum2 = NumberEnumSpecial.three

Comment: Swift 3.2 is the "Swift 3 mode of Xcode 9", and provides most Swift 4 features. – Anyway, I cannot reproduce the issue, there must be something else. Does it compile in a fresh new application?

Comment: What do you mean by "fresh new application" ? it compiles in a fresh new project Yes.

Comment: I have the exact same issue! Cannot figure out why it's happening.

Comment: @kakubei I now have 3 enums in my code with the same error and the same workaround :P

Comment: Yup. I’ve had to do the same. Funnily enough, they work if you declare them in the same file that uses them. Smells like a bug to me.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I had the same problem using Xcode 9.2 beta (9C32c), if it is a bug it is still not fixed in this version. I found a workaround to make the error disappear without overriding the `init`.

I changed this:

```
 NumberEnumSpecial.init(rawValue: 2)
```

to this:

```
 NumberEnumSpecial(rawValue: 2)
```

Comment: This is actually the correct answer.  In Swift you don't call the init method directly like in the first answer it's called implicitly when you use the code in the second example.